# Problema com a biblioteca math.h (referência indefinida para `sqrt')

Tags: c, biblioteca, matemática

Estou tendo problemas para compilar o código com a função `sqrt()` na linguagem C.

Erro:

> ```
> gcc exercicio_03.c  /tmp/ccGVE8ez.o: na função `distancia':
> exercicio_03.c:(.text+0x142): referência indefinida para `sqrt'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


#define TAM 2

typedef struct pontos{
    int x,y;
}dados;

void ler(dados *vetor);
int distancia(dados *vetor);

int main(){
  dados vetor[TAM];
  int resultado;
  ler(vetor);
  resultado=distancia(vetor);
  printf("\nA distancia entre eles e igual a %d\n\n\n",resultado);
return 0;
}

void ler(dados *vetor){
  for(int i=0;i<TAM;i++){
      printf("\nDigite as coordenadas do ponto %d",i);
      scanf("%d",&vetor[i].x);
      scanf("%d",&vetor[i].y);
  }
}

int distancia(dados *vetor){
  int x,y,retorno;
  x=vetor[0].x-vetor[1].x;
  y=vetor[0].y-vetor[1].y;
  retorno=(x*x)+(y*y);
  retorno=sqrt(retorno);
return retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa garantir que a biblioteca seja incluída na compilação, para isto use `-lm` na linha de comando do compilador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Comment: @RafaelTeixeira veja no [tour] a melhor maneira de dizer obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

No Code Blocks clicar em:
Settings -> Compiler -> Linker settings.
Na tela, do lado direito, onde está "Other linker options", digitar -lm e clicar em ok.